# Setting errno from user defined function

Tags: c, error-handling, standards, errno, c-standard-library

As far as I am aware of, most if not all standard C functions will set the global `errno` on failure to represent what happened, and thus the value can be used in logging, debugging or testing. Is it advisable for a user defined function to use this same behavior, or should we mimic it with a global variable `local_errno` that accepts the same values with the same meanings?

As am example, I’m writing a calculator, and I want an Addition function to report overflow:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
Add( int, int );

int
main( void )
{
  int a = 0, b = 0, res0 = 0;
  scanf(“%d %d”, &a, &b );

  res0 = Add(a,b);
  if( res0 == INF )
  {
    fprintf(stderr, “Error %s in Add\n”, strerror(errno));
    return(errno);
  }else
  {
    printf(“%d\n”, res0);
  }

  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int
Add( int l, int r )
{
  if( l == INT_MAX || r == INT_MAX )
  {
    errno = EOVERFLOW;
    return(INF);
  }
return(l+r);
}
```

Comment: you are free to use `errno` and in fact the functions whose potentially set `errno` do that only in case of an error, so generally you have to set first `errno` to 0 before to call them if you test `errno` after without considering the return value. If you use your own `errno` you are sure only you set it, if you use the 'real' `errno` you have to check all the functions you call to know if they potentially set it

Comment: so you can use `errno` to indicate/save an error on your own functions, but you take the risk to have it set not by you but by an other function even you did not wanted. To have your own `errno` is more 'robust' then

Comment: Thank you. I was more interested in whether or not it would be practical/advisable to do this.

Comment: i thought i answered about that

Comment: @bruno — Note that a function can set `errno` to a non-zero value even if it reports success.  You should only check `errno` if the called function reports failure and is documented to set `errno`.  Example: on Solaris (last checked on Solaris 8; things might have changed, but probably haven't), the I/O functions would set `errno` to `ENOTTY` routinely, even when they succeeded, if the output file was not a terminal.  No problem — they were within specification.

Comment: Hence checking for NULL, NAN or something similar right? And @bruno, you did yes.